# Specifying file name as a variable in the infile statement

Tags: sas

I am tying to convert a comma delimited text file to a pipe delimited file but my input file name (comma delimited file) is a variable (flname1). I am using the code below suggested by a stackoverflow member. The code works fine as long as I specify the file name in the infile statement but I don't know how to specify file name as a variable-

```
data _null_;
   enddate=date();
   flname1=compress("d:\temp\wq_" || year(enddate) || put(month(enddate),z2.) || ".txt");
   length x1-x6 $200;
   infile 'flname1' dsd dlm=',' truncover;
   file 'C:\temp\pipe.txt' dsd dlm='|';
   input x1-x6;
   put x1-x6;
run;
```

I am new to SAS and any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `filevar` option on the infile statement? https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm

Comment: Slightly offtopic, but to make your life easier, you should also look into using the `cat()` functions to perform concatenations.  There's several of them - `catt() cats() cat() catx()`.  They provide some quality-of-life improvements such as handling type conversions between numeric and character, trimming, and adding delimiters, to name a few.  Using the double-pipe notation `||` is now outdated but propagated by a lot of the legacy whitepaper and training materials out there.  It would also eliminate the need for that `compress()` statement.

Comment: What is the point of creating the pipe delimited file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to actually do this as a macro variable - this isn't a normal usage of `filevar` (which you'd use if you had a dataset with a bunch of filenames in it or something).

```
%let filename = d:\temp\wq_%sysfunc(today(),YYMMN6.).txt;
%put &=filename;

data _null_;
  length x1-x6 $200;
  infile "&filename." dsd dlm=',' truncover;
  file 'C:\temp\pipe.txt' dsd dlm='|';
  input x1-x6;
  put x1-x6;
run;
```

Macro variables are just text substitutions, so they can be used wherever you could type the same thing in.  They also don't need concatenating functions - any more than you have to concatenate when you type a word in - so it's easier to do.

Here, I use [`%sysfunc`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#z3514sysfunc.htm) to tell SAS to execute the today() function, and the second argument tells it how to format it - `YYMMN6.` is the format you look like you want (`201506` or similar).  Then just make sure to use `"` quotes not `'` quotes as the latter doesn't let the macro variable resolve.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `filevar` option in the `infile` statement, e.g.:

```
data _null_;
  enddate=date();
  flname1=compress("d:\temp\wq_"||year(enddate)||put(month(enddate),z2.)||".txt");
  length x1-x6 $200;
  infile myinputfile dsd dlm=',' filevar=flname1 truncover;
  file 'C:\temp\pipe.txt' dsd dlm='|';
  input x1-x6;
  put x1-x6;
run;
```

The [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/68024/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1rill4udj0tfun1fvce3j401plo.htm) explains more about the option and has an example of its use in Example 5.